# Redirect network packets from one IP-address to another in Windows 2008

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

My machine works with Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (x64) on board. There is ASP.NET app which tries to make outbound connection to IP 195.158.31.10:8000
This address is inaccessible from inside network. I need to redirect all packets sent for 195.158.31.10:8000 to 192.168.101.111:8000. In Linux I can do it with one command:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.101.111:8000
```

How can I do anything similar in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I found big bad solution. Big and bad because of it complexity so I can't recommend it to anybody.

My Windows Server was a virtual machine on VMware ESXi. Then I created another VM with Ubuntu 14.04 and VMWare Workstation on board. Next step was to move my old Windows VM into new Ubuntu VM. Yeah VM into VM. Windows network configured as NAT. Now I needed to forward ports from host OS to guest for transparent requests processing. I followed [this guide](https://brianoflan.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/how-to-redirect-network-traffic-to-your-virtual-machines-run-by-vmware-player-in-linux/) except paragraphs about setting *iptables*, I just edited *nat.conf* file and executed command from question above.

Now it works in this way.